# Use ng-bootstrap and bootstrap together in Angular 7

Tags: angular, webpack, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

Hope somebody can point me towards the right direction. I have looked on SO and Github issues but cannot find a resolution.

I've started to use both `"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap: "^4.0.1"` and `"bootstrap": "^4.2.1"` in the same Angular 7 project and the dropdowns stopped working. The dropdowns are vanilla bootstrap.

I suspect that `popper.js` is in the reason for that issue but cannot find how to configure my project properly.

Here is my configuration

**vendor.ts**:

```
...
import "bootstrap";
import "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
...
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

**webpack.config.js** :

```
module.exports = {
...
entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/app/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/app/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/app/bootstrap.ts'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.ts', '.js']
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(json|png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico|cur)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [
            { loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: true } }
          ]
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loaders: ['css-to-string-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
   ...
  ]
};
```

[Bootstrap website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/webpack/)  says that `popper.js` and `jquery` needn't be added to the entry point but where am I supposed to add them? I'd like to serve them myself and avoid CDNs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you attempting to use the JavaScript modules from Bootstrap in your Angular application? Are you using ng-bootstrap or Bootstrap dropdowns? If you are using ng-bootstrap, you do not need popper or jQuery, nor should you be adding Bootstrap JavaScript to your Angular project. ng-bootstrap is intended to entirely replace Bootstrap JS and has no dependencies on jQuery. Remove `import "bootstrap";`.

Comment: I'm using vanilla bootstrap dropdowns. Will update my post with that info.

Comment: You should be using ng-bootstrap since you are already using it. The whole point of that package is to remove the usage of jquery

Comment: @penleychan I agree and will be migrating my project towards ng-bootstrap. But for the time being, I need the 2 to work together.

Comment: You mentioned serving them through CDN being an option. Why not add these respective `<script>` tags to your `index.html`?

Comment: You shouldn't use bootstrap components in angular applications. it's bad practice, since it has dependencies on jQuery. You should use ngBootstrap only. Also, after testing several component libraries I noticed, ngBootrap isn't that good. Material, PrimeNG and MDBoostrap are way better

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if anything significant has changed in Angular 7 (didn't even know that you could eject in 7) but for Angular 5, somewhere in your `plugins` section, you should have a `ScriptsWebpackPlugin`:

```
    new ScriptsWebpackPlugin({
      "name": "scripts",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "filename": "scripts.bundle.js",
      "scripts": [
        "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
        "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ]
    }),
```

If it's not there, it's easy enough to import it from `@angular/cli/plugins/webpack` and put it in your plugins array yourself.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a potential solution. What is the npm package for `ScriptsWebpackPlugin` ? I didnt use the CLI for that project, I'm probably missing stuff.

Comment: It should come with @angular/cli; The path to the module is: `@angular/cli/plugins/webpack`

Comment: I see now that the entire @angular/cli/plugins/webpack module is no more.  Looks like an alternate solution is in order.

Comment: How do you have your project structured?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up injecting the scripts in my index.html using a Webpack plugin :

```
var HtmlWebpackExternalsPlugin = require('html-webpack-externals-plugin');

plugins : [
...
new HtmlWebpackExternalsPlugin({
  externals: [
    {
      module: 'jquery',
      entry: 'dist/jquery.min.js',
      global: 'jQuery',
    },
    {
      module: 'popper.js',
      entry: 'dist/umd/popper.min.js',
      global: 'popper',
    },
    {
      module: 'bootstrap',
      entry: 'dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
      global: 'bootstrap',
    }
  ],
}),
... 
]
```